# How to set MediaItemArtwork Image Fill in UITableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, mpmediaitem, artwork

I am trying to enter `MPMediaItemArtwork` Image into `UITableView's` cell's ImageView with following code.

```
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [[[self.arrayOfAlbums objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] representativeItem]valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
    UIImage *artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: cell.imageView.bounds.size];

if (artworkImage)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = artworkImage;

    }

    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"noArtwork.png"];
    }
```

It's okay when i insert Artwork image in `UITableView's` cell `ImageView`.

But when my artwork image is too small or big , it's happened like following pic.
Not in completely fill in cell's ImageView.

[image]

You see that? I want to set Fill with `Stretch` like iOS Music App

Here is Build-in App Artwork Image that set Completely fill with `Stretch`

[image]

I want to do like that.

So i used `cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;` however it's not effect.

So how can i do that?
Thanks you for your work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for calculating a new and fitting image;
Adjust `newRect` to the rect of your cell.

```
// scale and center the image

CGSize sourceImageSize = [artworkImage size];

// The rectangle of the new image
CGRect newRect;
newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 33);

// Figure out a scaling ratio to make sure we maintain the same aspect ratio
float ratio = MAX(newRect.size.width / sourceImageSize.width, newRect.size.height / sourceImageSize.height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, 1.0);

// Center the image in the thumbnail rectangle
CGRect projectRect;
projectRect.size.width = ratio * sourceImageSize.width;
projectRect.size.height = ratio * sourceImageSize.height;
projectRect.origin.x = (newRect.size.width - projectRect.size.width) / 2.0;
projectRect.origin.y = (newRect.size.height - projectRect.size.height) / 2.0;

[sourceImage drawInRect:projectRect];
UIImage *sizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

cell.imageView.image = sizedImage;
```

Comment: Thz for your answer bro.That is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
UIImage *artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: cell.imageView.bounds.size];
```

creates an image with the size of the cell. So, it's scaled in this line and the image won't be bigger than the cell and therefore it will not scale afterwards.

I would leave the image at it's original size or at a size 2x the cell size and leave the scaling up to `contentMode`.

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(artwork.bounds.size.width, artwork.bounds.size.height)
UIImage *artworkImage = [artwork imageWithSize: newSize];
```

Comment: thz . but when my artwork Image is big. It's stretch too much.How can i do that?I want to do the artwork image same size.

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean. Same size of what? What means "stretch too much"?

Comment: oh sorry. i mean that when i write with your code,some of Artwork is too big and stretch too much even it's reach cell's center. And i mean same size is when even my artwork is too big, i want to scale the size all the same like iOS Built-in App.Please check iOS Music App's Album.It's show all the artwork in exactly same size. even not a little beyond cell.imageView's size. Like that bro.How could i do that?

Comment: Do you set the contentMode (in code or in Interface Builder)? To which value?

Comment: yes bro i code cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;